# Is it possible to reference the jQuery UI dialog z-index counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am making a web application which utilizes several jQuery UI Dialogs. In order to keep track of them all, I have implemented a windows style "taskbar" with task items associated with each dialog. Clicking on these task items will "minimize" and "restore" the respective dialog.

I want to be able to differentiate between a dialog that is in the background and one that is in the fore. One that is in the fore should be minimized and one that is in the back should be brought to the fore, similar to MS Windows behaviour.

I am using jQuery UI's `moveToTop()` method to bring dialogs into the fore, but as far as I can tell there is no way to know whether or not a dialog is in the background or the foreground. I did notice that jQuery UI sorts dialogs by incrementing their z-index attribute, so it must be keeping track of dialog order with an index somewhere. Checking the UI dialog API doesn't show any direct way of accessing this value, however. And simply assigning the dialog a high z-index will either a) only work once or b) break the internet.

So, in short, how do I access the jQuery UI dialog z-index... index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out the answer to my own question:

I'm using the following code to handle the focus/minimize functionality:

```
var zindexes = [100] ; // Because jQuery UI starts its dialogs at z-index 101
$( ".ui-dialog" ).each(function( ) {
    // for each ui-dialog that is currently displayed, push the z-index to the array
    if( $( this ).css("display") === "block" )
        zindexes.push( $( this ).css("z-index") );
}) ;
// If z-index is less than the greatest index in the array, bring it to the fore
if($(class_str).parent().css("display") === "block" &&
   parseInt($(class_str).parent().css("z-index")) < Math.max.apply(null, zindexes))
    $(class_str).parent().css("z-index", Math.max.apply(null, zindexes)+1) ;
// If already in the fore then minimize/restore.
else $(class_str).dialog( "moveToTop" ), $(class_str).parent().toggle("blind", 250) ;
```

Not exactly what I had posited, but works nonetheless.